# htmlpurifier is not working with $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, post, tinymce, htmlpurifier

I am using HTML purifier with tinyMCE. I get the content put in the text area using  `$_POST['content'];` After that I use following code

```
require_once 'htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$content = $_POST['content'];
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier();
$pure_content = $purifier->purify($content);
```

However, when I echo $pure_content I get the code I entered without any changes. To make sure there is no problem with HTMLpurifier I used following code snippet

```
$value = '<script>Malicious script</script><b>Bold</b>';
$pure_content = $purifier->purify($value);
```

and after echo I get **Bold** So what am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**
the value inside $_POST['content'] is `<script>Malicious script</script><b>Bold</b>`

Comment: Can you show what is inside the post var?

Comment: Ok, I am editing the code.

Comment: According to the HTMLPurifier doc your implementation seems to be correct. Have you double checked that that "content" data doesn't get altered in any way, e.g html encoded etc.

Comment: Yes, It was getting html encoded. I was using tinyMCE which automatically encoded the text. Now, it is working.

Comment: @Asain Since you found a solution, go ahead and answer your own question, and accept it as an answer. :) (That way people searching for answers to the same issue can see it's resolved.)

Comment: Alright. I will add the answer now.

Answer (score 2):

I was using tinyMCE editor. The issue was that it automatically encode all the html code entered if any. I had to use

```
$decoded_content = html_entity_decode($content);
```

and then pass the result to html purifier.